# Link an action to winrt toast notifications in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications, windows-runtime

I'd like to make a Toast Notification and Winrt seems to be the best solution for what I'd like to do (button, textbox,...) I have made a basic script to make notifications with a textbox and a button:

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom

#create notifier
nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier(r"C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe")

#define your notification as

tString = """
<toast>

    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>New notifications</text>
            <text>Text</text>
            <text>Second text</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>

    <actions>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" placeHolderContent="Type a reply"/>
        <action
            content="Send"
            arguments="action=reply&amp;convId=01"
            activationType="background"
            hint-inputId="textBox"/>
            
        <action
            content="Button 1"
            arguments="action=viewdetails&amp;contentId=02"
            activationType="foreground"/>
    </actions>

</toast>
"""

#convert notification to an XmlDocument
xDoc = dom.XmlDocument()
xDoc.load_xml(tString)

#display notification
notifier.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xDoc))
```

The problem is that I can't get what the user entries in the textbox, start a function when "send" is pushed, start another function when Button 1 is pushed,...
I have been searching on Windows docs and forums for many hours but it's all made in C# and I don't know how to use it in Python.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue as you

Comment: Nope, I used Win10Toast Click which only allows me to click on notifications but if I find something I'll add it to the post (I still need to create custom notifications with GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use buttons [winrt](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/) like this:

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom

#create notifier
nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier(r"C:\Users\Romain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe")

#define your notification as

tString = """
<toast>

    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>New notifications</text>
            <text>Text</text>
            <text>Second text</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>

    <actions>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" placeHolderContent="Type a reply"/>
        <action
            content="Send"
            arguments="action=reply&amp;convId=01"
            activationType="background"
            hint-inputId="textBox"/>
            
        <action
            content="Button 1"
            arguments="action=viewdetails&amp;contentId=02"
            activationType="foreground"/>
    </actions>

</toast>
"""

#convert notification to an XmlDocument
xDoc = dom.XmlDocument()
xDoc.load_xml(tString)

# this is not called on the main thread.
def handle_activated(sender, _):
    print([sender, _])
    print('Button was pressed!')

# add the activation token.
activated_token = notification.add_activated(handle_activated)

#display notification
notifier.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xDoc))
```

Where I learnt about this: this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues/741).